# puppet, getting the $name when instantiating a resource type with an array

Tags: puppet

using puppet, i need to create three files, with this content:

```
/tmp/f1.txt: hello /tmp/f1.txt
/tmp/f2.txt: hello /tmp/f2.txt
/tmp/f3.txt: hello /tmp/f3.txt
```

i try as follows:

```
$path="/tmp/"
$my_files = ["$path/f1.txt", "$path/f2.txt", "$path/f3.txt"]
file { $my_files:
  ensure => file,
  content => "hello $name\n",
}
```

however this does not work because $name is undefined.

is there a variable that gets instantiated for each 'iteration' and that i can use?

ps: i am aware that i could create a new resource type as follows:

```
define file_with_content {
  file { $name:
    ensure => file,
    content => "hello $name\n",
  }  
}
$path="/tmp/"
$my_files = ["$path/f1.txt", "$path/f2.txt", "$path/f3.txt"]
file_with_content { $my_files: }
```

but this requires creating a new resource type,
and I cannot do this in my context (which is not explained here).

the question is, how to modify the first code to make it work, without defining a new resource type, nor executing shell code?

Answer (score 2):

You only can access the `namevar` for defined types. For Puppet's resources, the results are unpredictable - for example, `$name` for `File` will give you `main`, or the current `stage`. Additionally, you cannot pass/utilize extra parameters to Puppet's resources as they have their own set of parameters already.

The standard solution has been to wrap the `File` declaration in a defined type [like here](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/2860/how-to-get-namevar-value-inside-file-at-class/), like your first. Perhaps you can explain why that cannot be used, so some other solution could be devised?

Comment: I cannot use a define here because I am already in a define, and it seems that we cannot have nested defines.

Comment: Nested classes/defines are generally a bad idea: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_classes.html. They can be put outside without too much trouble and then referenced inside another class. What's stopping you?

Comment: you can have a define or class inside a class. but you cannot have a define inside a define. is this correct?